# XCode debugging error on real device

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

When trying to debug on my iPad mini, I get the error: XCode cannot run on the selected device. Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device. However, when debugging on the simulators, everything is ok. I've searched for this issue, but none of the answers i got helped. Anyone?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have enough reputation to edit your question to show an image of what your target's build settings look like?

Comment: no :(. But I found a solution. It was a very small mistake, under architectures there was: "armv7, armv7s". The "," was causing the error. Searched all nite on this issue. I changed it to "armv7 armv7s". Caused me a lot off stress. I have to publish this tomorrow. :). Thx for your time!